# Use Jenkins shared lib in parameters step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

trying to apply jenkins shared library to use in pipelines and want to add some choice parameters to don't update all pipelines with new values for example, created a class with static method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

class Envs implements Serializable {

  static giveMeParameters (script) {
    return [
      script.string(defaultValue: '', description: 'A default parameter', name: 'textParm')
    ]
  }
}
```

and trying to use it in pipeline:
pipeline {

```
parameters {

    string(name: 'ENV', defaultValue: 'staging', description: 'Please enter desire env name for app', trim: true)
    Envs.giveMeParameters (this)
}
```

but getting error:

```
WorkflowScript: 81: Invalid parameter type "giveMeParameters". Valid parameter types: [booleanParam, buildSelector, choice, credentials, file, gitParameter, text, password, run, string] @ line 81, column 9.
           giveMeParameters (this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `giveMeParameters()` return a params Array, but `parameters {}` not accept an Array.

To combine the params return by share lib and params of project, you can try as following.

```
projectParams = [
   // define project params here
   booleanParam(name: 'param1', defaultValue: false,
      description: ''
   ),
   string(name: 'param2', description: ''),
]

// extend common params return by share lib to projectParams
projectParams.addAll(giveMeParameters())

properties([parameters(projectParams)])

// you can choose put above lines either outside the pipeline{} block
// or put in a stage's script step

pipeline {
   
  stages {
    stage('Init') {
      steps {
        // you can choose put outside pipeline {}
        script {
          projectParams = [
             // define project params here
             booleanParam(name: 'param1', defaultValue: false,
                description: ''
             ),
             string(name: 'param2', description: ''),
          ]

          // extend common params return by share lib to projectParams
          projectParams.addAll(giveMeParameters())

          properties([parameters(projectParams)])          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```